# Conditional title in tcolorbox: not equivalent to an untitled box when empty

Tags: macros, spacing, tcolorbox, conditionals, key-value

Consider the following code :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifmtarg}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\makeboxtitle}[1]{\@ifmtarg{#1}{}{\textsc{\textbf{#1}\strut}}}
\makeatother
\newtcolorbox{untitledbox}{
    enhanced, breakable, sharp corners, center title,
    colframe = MaterialIndigo900,
    colback = MaterialIndigo50,
    colbacktitle = MaterialRed900,
}
\newtcolorbox{titledbox}[1]{
    enhanced, breakable, sharp corners, center title,
    colframe = MaterialIndigo900,
    colback = MaterialIndigo50,
    colbacktitle = MaterialRed900,
    title = \makeboxtitle{#1},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{untitledbox} This is an untitled box.\end{untitledbox}
\begin{titledbox}{} This is a titled box.\end{titledbox}
\begin{titledbox}{A title} This is a titled box.\end{titledbox}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following result :

[image: Result]

The problem is that even if there is no title specified, the second box is not equivalent to the first box (empty title line in red still appears). How to modify the `\makeboxtitle` command or the `titledbox` environment so that when the title is empty it appears as if there was no title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the title to be an optional argument (because it *is* optional in your setting) and to use the `xparse` library:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor-material}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\newtcolorbox{untitledbox}{
    enhanced, breakable, sharp corners, center title,
    colframe = MaterialIndigo900,
    colback = MaterialIndigo50,
    colbacktitle = MaterialRed900,
}
\NewTColorBox{titledbox}{o}{
    enhanced, breakable, sharp corners, center title,
    colframe = MaterialIndigo900,
    colback = MaterialIndigo50,
    colbacktitle = MaterialRed900,
    fonttitle=\scshape,
    IfValueT={#1}{title = \strut#1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{untitledbox} This is an untitled box.\end{untitledbox}

\begin{titledbox} This is a titled box.\end{titledbox}

\begin{titledbox}[A title] This is a titled box.\end{titledbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\bfseries\scshape` is not a usual combination and with most fonts you'd get just `\bfseries`.

You might do it with a mandatory argument, but I don't think it's the best approach.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor-material}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{untitledbox}{
    enhanced, breakable, sharp corners, center title,
    colframe = MaterialIndigo900,
    colback = MaterialIndigo50,
    colbacktitle = MaterialRed900,
}
\tcbset{
  my title/.code{
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\tcbset{title=\strut#1}\fi
  },
}
\newtcolorbox{titledbox}[1]{
    enhanced, breakable, sharp corners, center title,
    colframe = MaterialIndigo900,
    colback = MaterialIndigo50,
    colbacktitle = MaterialRed900,
    fonttitle=\scshape,
    my title={#1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{untitledbox} This is an untitled box.\end{untitledbox}

\begin{titledbox}{} This is a titled box.\end{titledbox}

\begin{titledbox}{A title} This is a titled box.\end{titledbox}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use `ifmtarg`, `tcolorbox` will check for an empty title. The way you set things up `tcolorbox` will not find an empty title, but instead will find `\makeboxtitle{}` in the title (this is not empty) and hence will produce the output for a non-empty title (meaning the red background of a title shows up).

Now `\makeboxtitle{}` will use `\@ifmtarg` to check whether the title is empty and if it isn't will set up some font commands. Instead you could use the `fonttitle` key of `tcolorbox` to specify the used font and let `tcolorbox` decide when the title is empty. This is what the following does:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor-material}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{untitledbox}{
    enhanced, breakable, sharp corners, center title,
    colframe = MaterialIndigo900,
    colback = MaterialIndigo50,
    colbacktitle = MaterialRed900,
}
\newtcolorbox{titledbox}[1]{
    enhanced, breakable, sharp corners, center title,
    colframe = MaterialIndigo900,
    colback = MaterialIndigo50,
    colbacktitle = MaterialRed900,
    fonttitle = \scshape\bfseries\strut,
    title = {#1},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{untitledbox} This is an untitled box.\end{untitledbox}
\begin{titledbox}{} This is a titled box.\end{titledbox}
\begin{titledbox}{A title} This is a titled box.\end{titledbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But what if it's not only a matter of font and I need title to call a personalized macro?

Comment: @Vincent This might be an x/y problem. What else does your macro need to do? `tcolorbox` allows a few other customizations via its key=value interface (e.g., `title style`). And if you really need complete freedom you can use the `detach title` option and completely control the placement of your title yourself (see the manual for more on this).